# Url for cloning repo in GitHub Desktop

Tags: github, hyperlink, github-desktop

I've seen the button in GitHub that says `Open with GitHub Desktop`. What is the url to clone repositories **using GitHub Desktop**, so I can open custom links to GitHub desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the format is `x-github-client://openRepo/https://github.com/<user>/<repo>`.

Example

```html
<a href="x-github-client://openRepo/https://github.com/ChocolateLoverRaj/release-mono-repo">This is a link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL to clone is the HTTPs, one. See the image below:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: While that is the URL to clone it, the question asks about the URL to clone it with GitHub Desktop. Sorry for making the question a little unclear. I will edit the question.

Comment: To clone it in GitHub desktop, can't you just sign in, and choose the repo you want to clone from your GitHub repo? Like, you first make the repo in GitHub, and then you go to GitHub desktop and clone it from the list of repos.