# URL scheme for opening a local repository using GitHub Desktop

Tags: github, hyperlink, github-desktop

Is there a URL scheme I can use to open a *local* repository using GitHub Desktop?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68231796/url-for-cloning-repo-in-github-desktop) that shows how to use URL to open a remote repository. The basic syntax is

`x-github-client://openRepo/https://github.com/<user>/<repo>`

I cannot figure out, though, how instead of `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>` insert the path to a local repository and make it work. If I just type the path to the folder, nothing happens.